# Android send broadcast from running service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

How May I send broadcast from running service? I tried to send broadcast and i can receive my all messages when service has completed. I would like to receive message from my activity while my service is running.

Comment: You should show what you've tried to date.

Comment: Do you want to receive data from your service in the activity? You need to register a broadcast receiver on your activity to receive the broadcast.

Comment: @AutonomousApps ok,I will add some code

Comment: @MartinRevert  I can receive data from my service in my activity, but i received all my message in activity after service has finished working. I want to get data while my service is running